# .htaccess baseurl -> mywebshop.nl/shop/baseurl-extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Currently i'm working on a webshop.
The code for this webshop is stored at 1 single point.
I pointed 800 domainnames that I need to point to the location of my webshop.
This webshop is selling domainnames

So for example. My store is located on: www.mystore.com

I've a pointer from www.foobar.com

This is the function I need (works)

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^foobar.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mystore.com/shop/foobar-com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As you can see, i've used the url name as an ID. 
I need this ID to get the correct product from my webshop.
How can I automate this? So how can I make sure that every url different then www.mystore.com redirects to www.mystore.com/shop/baseurl*dash*extension ?

Of course, I could type them all out but would take to much effort.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})(.*)$ http://www.mystore.com/shop/$2-$3/$4 [R=301,L]
```

This rule redirects:
http://www.foobar.com?id=1
to
http://www.mystore.com/shop/foobar-com/?id=1